# nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here

Tags: centos, nginx

I get the following error message when trying to configure server:

```
[]# nginx -s reload
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/hello-world.conf:1
```

Configuration is as follows:

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**:

```
...
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    ...

    index   index.html index.htm;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location / {
        }
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/hello-world.conf**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.server;

    root    i/var/www/hello-world;
    index   index.html;

    location / {
    }
}
```

nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
OS: CentOS-70-64-minimal

I suppose it doesn't get that `server` directive is inside `http` because when I copy content of hello-world.conf to nginx.conf right after `include` it works.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Looks like a possible problem with something in one or more of the include files.